# Environment variables set via System#setProperty used in Spring application.yml

Tags: java, spring

I have been reading [Baeldung's Testcontainer HowTo](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testcontainers-integration-test#common-configuration) where in section 4 it is mentioned:

> In the start() method we use `System#setProperty` to set connection parameters as environment variables.
> We can now put them in our application.properties file:
>
> ```
> spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
> spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
> spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
> ```

I tried this approach - albeit with using Junit5 and hence no `@ClassRule` to fire up the container as stated in the tutorial, yet `@Container` instead.

It turns out: These environment variables are seemingly not used in the Spring context. They seems to be empty, yet e.g. the DB URL apparently defaults to `localhost:5432` when using PostgreSQL.

My question:
**I wonder if and how programatically defined environment variables would work in an `application.properties` or `application.yml`.**

Would not `@SpringBootTest` load my context as defined in `application.yml` (with empty env vars) *before* the Container is initialized and defines those `DB_` variables?

It would be nice if this approach actually worked, because I believe this would help me to trigger Liquibase prior to test execution, although there is certainly a way to do that programmatically as well.

PS: With a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` which programatically sets the data source properties, the test does work.

**** EDIT ****

I found out that the feature of setting properties via programmatically defined env vars *does* work. However, I was misled due to the following setup:

My project base directory has a subdir `config` with `config/application.yml` as the externalized config source in it. I thought that is a good idea - better than placing a config in `src/main/resources`, because - unless one explicitly excludes it - it would land in the `jar` and I would not necessarily want that.

However, I did believe that a `src/test/resources/application.yml` (further called: T) would override any settings obtained from `config/application.yml` (further called: P). Apparently not quite, which I found out after adding Liquibase:

P contains `spring.liquibase.enable=false` while T contains `spring.liquibase.enable=true` and `spring.liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/foo.yaml`. Launching the tests, I see no Liquibase updates. Setting `spring.liquibase.enable=true` in P, however, results in Liquibase updates being applied during integration tests.
Also, *not* setting `spring.liquibase.changeLog=classpath:/db/foo.yaml` in T makes Liquibase complain about a missing changelog file (it defaults to some file name I do not use). That means, T must be read after all. But apparently, properties set in P are not overridden in T (which may be a feature I was not aware of).
Such overriding does work, however, when moving P to `src/main/resources/application.yml`.

Also removed the Junit4 annotation `@RunWith` following @M.Deinum's good remark.

**** END OF EDIT ****

Full test class:

```java
// @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test-postgres")
class MyRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MyRepository repository;

    @Container
    static JdbcDatabaseContainer<?> databaseContainer = IntegrationTestPostgresContainer.getInstance();

    @Test
    void test() {
        assertEquals("postgres", System.getProperty("DB_USERNAME"));
        assertEquals("postgres", System.getProperty("DB_PASSWORD"));
        assertTrue(databaseContainer.isRunning());
    }
}
```

Container extension:

```java
public class IntegrationTestPostgresContainer extends PostgreSQLContainer<IntegrationTestPostgresContainer> {

    private static final String IMAGE_VERSION = "postgres:12.3";
    private static IntegrationTestPostgresContainer container;

    private IntegrationTestPostgresContainer() {
        super(IMAGE_VERSION);
    }

    public static IntegrationTestPostgresContainer getInstance() {
        if (container == null) {
            container = new IntegrationTestPostgresContainer()
                .withDatabaseName("mddb")
                .withUsername("postgres")
                .withPassword("postgres");
        }
        return container;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        super.start();
        System.setProperty("DB_URL", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("DB_USERNAME", container.getUsername());
        System.setProperty("DB_PASSWORD", container.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // noop
    }

}
```

Initializer, to be added to the test context via `@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {DataSourceContextInitializer.class})` in order to make the test pass:

```java
public class DataSourceContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    private final static JdbcDatabaseContainer<?> CONTAINER = IntegrationTestPostgresContainer.getInstance();

    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                "spring.datasource.url=" + CONTAINER.getJdbcUrl(),
                "spring.datasource.username=" + CONTAINER.getUsername(),
                "spring.datasource.password=" + CONTAINER.getPassword()
            )
                .applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
    }
}
```

`application.yml`

```yaml
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: integration-test-postgres
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
```

Comment: When setting the system variables the ordering is important. As the container needs to start before the Spring APplication context is started, if not setting them is pretty useless. Another thing is it appears as if you are mixing JUnit4 (`@RunWIth`) with JUnit5 which is probably also an issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry, I wrote a long comment about `@ExtendWith` sorting out the issue, but I accidentally launched tests in the wrong profile. However, there is an interesting issue with properties which I will describe in my original question. Nevertheless, thanks for the heads-up